# Line break in ResourceDictionary string not working

Tags: xaml

I have the following:

```
<sys:String x:Key="NoDeviceAlert" xml:space="preserve">Your device is currently disabled.&#10;&#13;Please ensure it is turned on and connected.</sys:String>
```

However it doesn't work. The TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource NoDeviceAlert}" Style="{DynamicResource msgTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

keeps both sentences on a single line, but removes the decimal values. I have also tried hex values as well as /r/n.

How can this not work?

**UPDATE**

```
<Style x:Key="msgTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFC8DBE7" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Project;component/Utilities/Resources/Fonts/frutiger.ttf#Frutiger Linotype" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

ResourceDictionary sys namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

The application is for Windows desktop and using .net 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `xml:space="preserve"` affects only working of XML parser. So line breaks, tabs and spaces will stay preserved.
Instead of typing explicit newline chars just press enter:

```
    <sys:String x:Key="NoDeviceAlert" xml:space="preserve">Your device is currently disabled.
Please ensure it is turned on and connected.</sys:String>
```

Comment: It's still on a single line... even splitting it into separate lines causes the period to be right beside the P character.

Comment: No, it works for me. May be style `msgTextStyle` makes some changes. Please provide it in the post.

Comment: I've added the style in the post.

Comment: Steel works whell. Need more info.
How you declared `xmlns:sys`?
Which version of the framework/WPF you use?
May be it is app for phones?

Comment: Added more to the post. Cheers.

Comment: More testing done, works on one machine but not the other.

Comment: Can you suppose a differences? OS version. Locale settings.

Comment: Windows 10 it works, Windows 7 Embedded it does not (which is where it needs to work) Looking into locales on the embedded 7.

Comment: If I remove the style, it still does not work. If I remove the resource dictionary it does work inline instead of a dynamic resource. But I need the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use

**&#x 0a;**

like a line break (without this space inside).
It should be work.

Comment: Is there suppose to be a space in between the x and 0?